# Visual Studio: Inserting reference to executable path within C# program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have two C# projects in Visual Studio (2012 Express for Desktop).  One is a console application, the other is a library of Nunit tests.  I want the test library to be able to call the console application using Process.

I can hardcode the path to the executable, but I'd rather not do this.  Is there a way to get Visual Studio to embed the path string in my test library?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this snippet to find `Assembly` `CodeBase` (`Location` might be wrong when executing tests, because of temporary folder creation by many test runners)

```
var codeBase = typeof(AnyTypeFromAnotherAssembly).Assembly.CodeBase;
var uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
```

Another way is to find by it's name, but I don't recommend even to hardcode it's name, because you will want to safely change it's name.

```
var codeBase= AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                    .GetAssemblies()
                    .First(assembly => assembly.ManifestModule.Name == "MyAssembly.dll")
                    .CodeBase
```

Do not hardcode full path anywhere, because it will vary from environment to environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options I can think of:

1) Add a Resource file (`.resx`) and then reference the Resource key (strongly typed)

2) Add the path in a config file.  `AppSettings` might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

to find the path of the currently executing assembly.